# Chrome DevTools console keeps targeting extension scripts

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Whenever I open the developer console in Google Chrome, the "context window" of the console is always an extension background page (a `chrome-extension://` URI), instead of `top`. Like this:

[image: Chrome DevTools console with the window context chooser defaulting to a chrome-extension:// URI]

I can manually click on the dropdown and change it back to `top`, but this is frustrating because I often forget and wonder why none of my commands are working... Also, it will revert when I close and re-open the console. I could not find a setting that pertains to this.

Why is this occurring? How can I fix it?

Comment: @Gideon: Thanks, that question is helpful, but its accepted answer is not correct. I am still having the issue in Chrome Canary.

Comment: This was fixed before. It looks like it has regressed again! Very frustrating. I'll add an update on the other post and open a new bug report for the regression. Still don't need two SO questions for the issue though.

Comment: @Gideon Agreed. When the other question has been updated, I'll close this one. Somehow I never saw the other question before asking this one, even though I searched both Google and SO...

Comment: Added an update. No problem.